# Is there a way to encrypt files in bitbucket?

Tags: git, encryption, bitbucket

I am doing some work for a client and when I am finished with the work they want me to send it to them encrypted. Is there a way for me to encrypt my code within bitbucket or do I have to encrypt before hand?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what's driving their request? I have to wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on your client's end.

Comment: What are you sending to them? If it is an archive of a cloned repository, then you can easily encrypt that archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git-crypt 
Reference : https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt